# How to add/get items in Combobox in excel VBA

Tags: vba

How do I add/get (Desc as valuember and name as displaymember same like .NET) to the combobox and listbox?

Basically, I want to show Name to the user and after selecting Name from combobox, I want to get the **Desc**  based on **Name** selection for further use.

using below code I am adding **Name**  into the combobox but don't know how add **DESC** as itmeindexColumn(which is DESC column from DB).
(same like valuemember,Displaymember in .NET ComboBox)

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqltextexec As String
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sqltextexec = " SELECT Name , Name + '-' + Code 'Desc' from Employee "
    rs.Open sqltextexec, cn
    rs.MoveFirst
With Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1
    .Clear
    Do
        .ComboBox1.AddItem rs![Name]
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a typo in the presented snippet

> `.ComboBox1.AddItem rs![Name]` --> `.AddItem rs![Name]`

To refer to the selected index and the text of the combobox, use the `.ListIndex` and `.Value` respectively. You can also use `.Text` for the text. Example:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Debug.Print ComboBox1.ListIndex, ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: but how can i add Value into combobox and combobox Value item should not show to the user.